# How to eliminate UI thread GC freezes?

Tags: c#, uwp, garbage-collection, uwp-xaml, tdlib

My app randomly freezes for 500ms intervals (but after some time of running can be up to 3 seconds). It's especially noticeable when trying to type text.

Here is a dotTrace screenshot with the problem: [image]

But allocations are not that big. Only 13MB were allocated during 25 seconds.
[image]

Is there a way to reduce GC pauses to something acceptable like 100ms?

Comment: Share the code of the OnSelectionChanged. From your images it looks like you're doing some heavy operations on UI thread.

Comment: Also try moving GC collection on the separate thread https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcconcurrent-element

Comment: @MaxNaumov .NET can't do background collection for 0-1 generations

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve] to help us further check the problem for you?